# Add dynamic id to option in ng-options

Tags: html, angularjs, select, ng-options

Is it possible to add a dynamic attribut `id` to an `option`, when I use `ng-options` in a `select` to loop my list and generate my dropdown? It works, if I use an `ng-repeat` loop, because there I can put the attribut `id` directly in the `option` tag an increment it with `$index`. Is this also possible with `ng-options`? Here is my code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedOption1;
  $scope.selectedOption2;

  $scope.myList = [{
    text: "1"
  }, {
    text: "2"
  }, {
    text: "3"
  }, {
    text: "4"
  }, {
    text: "5"
  }, ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <!--BUILD DROPDOWN WITH NG-OPTIONS LOOP-->
  <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option as option.text for option in myList"></select>

  <!--BUILD DROPDOWN AND SET ATTRIBUT ID WITH NG-REPEAT LOOP-->
  <select ng-model="selectedOption2">
    <option id="option_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="option in myList">{{option.text}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Screenshot of both `select` (red border are the id's):

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: With `ng-options` you can only set `text` and `value` of the `option` and not `id`.

Comment: @Aruna Ok I expected such an answer - thanks. :-)

Comment: @Aruna How can I modify the value in a ng-options loop? At the moment there is a value 0-5 for each option (see screenshot). Can I set there also a text and increment it with $index like in the ng-repeat? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do, I will post the answer for this :-)

Comment: @Aruna This would be very nice, thanks!

Comment: Please have a look below. I have explained a bit whats happening with Angular in terms of rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `track by` option :

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="obj.text for obj in myList track by obj.value">
```

But then, you have to modify your object a little bit :

```
$scope.myList = [{
    text: "1",
    value: "option_1"
}, {
    text: "2",
    value: "option_2"
}, {
    text: "3",
    value: "option_3"
}, {
    text: "4",
    value: "option_4"
}, {
    text: "5",
    value: "option_5"
}, ];
```

This should do the trick.

**EDIT** [The plunker to test it](https://plnkr.co/edit/mfbHcu4XqAJFgRUPyWWY?p=preview)

**EDIT 2** For those who want a fast answer, you also can do this :

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="obj.text for obj in myList track by option + obj.text">
```

And in the js file add :

```
$scope.option = 'option_';
$scope.myList = [{
    text: "1"
}, {
    text: "2"
}, {
    text: "3"
}, {
    text: "4"
}, {
    text: "5"
}, ];
```

Comment: Can you make a code snippet? I tried to update my but it prints me some errors and my dropdown with the ng-options loop is empty..

Comment: I just modified it to cope with your needs. See the second `select` & inspect it to understand. If you don't, comment below and I'll make another edit to explain it ot you.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the answer below.

`Angular` will always render the value as `index` starting from `0`. Don't worry about this. Since it will have a internal reference and will update the modal accordingly.

I have placed a `span` below to see the `value` of the selected item.

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedOption1;
  $scope.selectedOption2;

  $scope.myList = [{
    text: "1"
  }, {
    text: "2"
  }, {
    text: "3"
  }, {
    text: "4"
  }, {
    text: "5"
  }, ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <!--BUILD DROPDOWN WITH NG-OPTIONS LOOP-->
  <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="('option_' + (myList.indexOf(option) + 1)) as option.text for option in myList"></select>
  <br/><br/>
  Selected: <span><b>{{selectedOption}}</b></span>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. What I exactly need is, the text option_{{$index}}, within the value attribute so it would be: value="option_1" and so on. I need this for some coded ui tests. Is this possible to modify exactly the string in the value attribut?. At the moment it's still 0 to 4 automaticly..?

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedOption1;
  $scope.selectedOption2;

  $scope.myList = [{
    text: "1"
  }, {
    text: "2"
  }, {
    text: "3"
  }, {
    text: "4"
  }, {
    text: "5"
  }, ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    
<select ng-model="selectedOption2">
 <option ng-repeat="d in myList track by $index" ng-value="'Option_'+($index+1)">
   {{d.text}}
 </option>
  
</select>
  {{selectedOption2}}
</div>
```

Comment: If you read my question again, I already have such a solution with ng-repeat, but I need the same with ng-options if possible... So this isn't an answer I really need..